# cakin_make returns the error '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRTIMULib'

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to catkin_make the imu package from this [link](https://github.com/jeskesen/i2c_imu/blob/master/README.md)
But I'm getting the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRTIMULib
```

From as far as I can tell the library is include and linked in the CMake.txt

Does the location of the library file matter? It's currently in ~/catkin_ws/src/i2c_imu-master/src

Thanks for any help, the CMake.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(i2c_imu)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  sensor_msgs
  roscpp
  tf
  angles
)

find_library(RTIMULib libRTIMULib.so)
message(STATUS "RTIMULib: ${RTIMULib }")

catkin_package(
CATKIN_DEPENDS sensor_msgs roscpp tf angles
)

include_directories(
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(i2c_imu_node src/i2c_imu_node.cpp)

target_link_libraries(i2c_imu_node
RTIMULib
${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

**EDIT:**
The output of catkin_make after adding `message(STATUS "RTIMULib: ${RTIMULib }")` after `find_library(RTIMULib ..):` in the CMakeList.txt.

```
Base path: /home/nvidia/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src -
DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/devel -
DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.8
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - i2c_imu
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'i2c_imu'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(i2c_imu-master)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Error at i2c_imu-master/CMakeLists.txt:19 (message):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/i2c_imu-master/CMakeLists.txt:19

  when parsing string

    RTIMULib: ${{RTIMULib }}

  syntax error, unexpected cal_SYMBOL, expecting }} (22)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

See also "/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282508/cakin_make-returns-the-error-%27/usr/bin/ld:-cannot-find--lrtimulib%27/) by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-13**:
Can you add the following line to the `CMakeLists.txt` and add whatever gets printed to your OP? Add this *after* `find_library(RTIMULib ..)`:

```
message(STATUS "RTIMULib: ${RTIMULib}")
```

**Comment by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on 2018-02-18**:
Thanks for your reply! The question has been updated with the information you asked for

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-19**:
You have a space in there after the variable name. CMake might not like that.

And as @ahendrix writes: you probably need to install the library. The `message(STATUS ..)` was just to see whether the library is actually found or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like that ROS package is just a wrapper for an IMU library, [RTIMULib2](https://github.com/RTIMULib/RTIMULib2). You should probably install that library.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on 2018-03-11**:
Thanks @ahendrix! You're 100% right